# Load different URL's in Web View

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I have an app where I would like to push a button and have the user taken to a web view. However, I would like a particular page to load depending on the button that's pushed. Originally I thought about creating a separate web view for each button, but that only caused more issues, which I won't go into. So my question is: How can I load different URL's into a web view, based on whether a particular button is pushed?

I thought about using the `prepareForSegue` method, but thought that might be over complicating things. Any direction would be great.

Comment: did you means you have a viewController and some buttons on it. When user click on each button, system will be switch to corresponding webView?

Comment: Yes, for the most part. I have a viewController with buttons. They did go to different webviews...That's what I tried. I'm hoping that I can use the same web view, and just load a different URL.

Comment: is the webview on other viewController or in the same as the buttons? Because if is in other viewController prepare for segue would be the right way to do it which isn't really complicate

Comment: The viewController & buttons are in one view, and would like to load a new webView

Answer (score 4):

so you must create new viewController with UIWebView inside it. 
On newViewController create a NSString property named url or somethings like that

example:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *url;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

On buttonTouchUpInside event in oldViewController

```
UIStoryboard *mainStorybroad = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    newViewController *webViewController = [mainStorybroad instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webviewIdentifier"];
webViewController.url = @"url string";
```

and final, in newViewController you just do:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for .h and .m File

Create a XIB and Put UIWebView on it and bind it to the class.

For Header File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewWebViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    NSString *currentURL;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;

}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *currentURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;

@end
```

For Implementation File (.m)

```
#import "NewWebViewController.h"

@interface NewWebViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewWebViewController
@synthesize currentURL;
@synthesize activityView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    webView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.currentURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];


    self.activityView = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.activityView.tag = 1;
    self.activityView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    UIView *customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)] autorelease];
    self.activityView.center = customView.center;
    [customView addSubview:self.activityView];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView] autorelease];
    [self.activityView startAnimating];
}

#pragma mark UIWebView Delegate
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.activityView startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.activityView stopAnimating];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error %@",[error description]);
    [self.activityView stopAnimating];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    [webView stopLoading];
    webView.delegate = nil;
    webView = nil;
    self.activityView = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    webView.frame = self.view.frame;
    return YES;//(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
} 

- (void) dealloc {
    [currentURL release];
    [webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Here how to use this

```
- (void) openWebViewControllerWithURL:(NSString*) url {
    if (!url) {
        return;
    }
    NewWebViewController *vController = [[NewWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewWebViewController" bundle:nil];
    vController.currentURL = url;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vController animated:YES];
    [vController release];   
}
```

On click of button just pass the URL you want to load

like this

```
 [self openWebViewControllerWithURL:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Comment: I'll admit it is very thorough and well written; but, I has hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: I'm sure it does! It is a great answer, which is why I gave it +1, so please don't think I'm not grateful.

Comment: @Blaine what could be simpler solution then this ? If you know much simpler solution let me know as well.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use use `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: prepareForSegue is for storyboard and my solution is without storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you link the button in IB to just do a modal transition to the view controller page? Then, in the viewdidload on the new view controller, the code should look something like this:

```
    NSString *fullURL = @"google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

How many buttons do you have? If it's just a couple, then I would just create an extra couple view controllers. If it's a bunch, you could always create a global variable (I can already hear the cringing...) and set the variable equal to the desired URL depending on which button was pushed.

Comment: This is basically what I've already done. Now I just want the URL to be different based on which button I use to get to this point.

Comment: @Blaine I see. There are a few ways to go about it, including the prepareForSegue method which you stated. What happened when you tried the method in my answer, or the prepareForSegue method? I can update my answer as well after knowing a bit more if you are still seeking a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I load different URL's into a web view, based on whether a particular button is pushed?

There are two basic approaches to recognizing different buttons:

- **separate actions:** You can create a separate action method for each button, and then just hook up each button to the corresponding action.
- **single action:** You can create a single action for all the buttons, and use some property of the buttons to differentiate between them.

The first one looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)button1Action:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1]];
}

- (IBAction)button2Action:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2]];
}
```

The second looks like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonsAction:(UIButton*)sender
{
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case button1Tag:
            [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1]];
            break;
        case button2Tag:
            [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2]];
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work if the you have 2 different view controllers? I have a `homeViewController` and a `webViewController`. The buttons are on the `homeViewController` and want to load different `URL` into the single `webViewController`

Comment: @Blaine Works fine, but instead of setting the webview's request directly, you should tell the web view's view controller to do it. Could be something as simple as: `webViewController.url = url1;`. You'd write the `setUrl` method to create the URL request and pass that on to the web view.